# Graficar con Python, Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Tengo que graficar a partir de un archivo csv similar a este:

```
Cedula,Genero,Placa,Tipo,Multa,Fecha
0931921407,Femenino,GYS-9575,Automovil,Grave,2016-06-13
0910703362,Masculino,GSF-7654,Automovil,Leve,2016-02-18
0931921408,Femenino,GOI-3298,Automovil,Muy grave,2016-01-04
0987654321,Masculino,ETR-9873,Camioneta,Grave,2016-08-05
0931921407,Femenino,GYS-9575,Automovil,Grave,2016-06-13
0910703362,Masculino,GSF-7654,Automovil,Leve,2016-02-18
0931921408,Femenino,GOI-3298,Automovil,Muy grave,2016-01-04
0987654321,Masculino,ETR-9873,Camioneta,Grave,2016-08-05
0931921407,Femenino,GYS-9575,Automovil,Grave,2016-06-13
0910703362,Masculino,GSF-7654,Automovil,Leve,2016-02-18
0931921408,Femenino,GOI-3298,Automovil,Muy grave,2016-01-04
0987654321,Masculino,ETR-9873,Camioneta,Grave,2016-08-05
0931921407,Femenino,GYS-9575,Automovil,Grave,2016-06-13
```

Mi principal problema es que de todas las formas que intento tengo el error de

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/Downloads/x/xx/aaa.py", line 14, in <module>
    my_plot = grp.plot(kind='bar')
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 311, in __call__
    return self._groupby.apply(f)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 651, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 655, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1527, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 647, in f
    return func(g, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 309, in f
    return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 3740, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2614, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2441, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1026, in generate
    self._compute_plot_data()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1135, in _compute_plot_data
    'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

siendo esto lo que escribo en el codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


lectura=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",",",parse_dates=['Fecha'])

equis=lectura[["Tipo","Multa"]]
equis.head()

grp=equis.groupby("Multa")
grp.size()
my_plot = grp.plot(kind='bar')`



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


lectura=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",",",parse_dates=['Fecha'])

equis=lectura[["Tipo","Multa"]]
equis.head()

grp=equis.groupby("Multa")
grp.size()
my_plot = grp.plot(kind='bar')
```

En [este enlace](http://postimg.org/gallery/1w5764h8c/) se encuentran los gráficos que tengo que realizar.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. Por favor no publiques una respuesta para agregar información a tu pregunta. Existe la opción "editar" para ese propósito.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando haces una operación de agrupación (`groupby`) se te crea un objeto especial.

```
>>> print(type(grp))
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

Es una especie de diccionario con información de los grupos. Lo que parece que quieres graficar, y tienes métodos para ello, son objetos de estructuras de datos (e.g., `Series`, `DataFrame`,...). Cuando aplicas una operación sobre `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`, como cuando aplicas el método `size`, te devuelve, por ejemplo en tu caso, una `Series`.

```
>>> print(type(grp.size()))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Si lo que quieres graficar es el resultado de `grp.size()` deberías hacerlo así:

```
>>> grp.size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Y el resultado sería este:

[image: Gráfica ejemplo]

Si no es eso lo que quieres, por favor, especifica un poco mejor la pregunta y rehago la respuesta.